# Windows not seeing tidyverse installed outside of RStudio

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to run an R/ruby code that cleans a number of CSV files and generates another one. I have RStudio and tidyverse installed but the code keeps failing due to "Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called 'tidyverse'"

I have tried reinstalling R and RStudio and tidyverse. RStudio can see tidyverse is installed but this other script cannot.

Comment: Run .libPaths() i n each of the R instances to find out which library each isusing.  Also run R.version.string and system.file() and look for differences.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide more information regarding the context in which you attempt to run the script? Describe the steps taken. Though not completely applicable to your case, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I would run these in RStudio?

Comment: @Aurèle I am attempting to run the ruby/r code via command line

Comment: You have to run this using both methods of running R and then compare the output.